# minimize maximize buttons missing tightenvnc Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, gnome, vnc

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, I followed the instructions of how to install Vnc via page below:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04

Everything is working fine except I am missing my minimize/maximize/close buttons.

[image]

I've followed many threads that suggest using the Gnome Tweak tool and even running the command below through terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

Nothing seems to work.

**Note**: that this only occurs while I am remotely accessing my computer through VNC. My actual Ubuntu desktop does not have this problem.

Comment: Did you note that the min/max/close buttons were missing from the graphic of the XFCE window in the instructions you followed? I am having this trouble too however, I am using a VPS and the console view of XFCE shows the buttons. I believe this may indicate that this is a tightVNC server issue not working correctly with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Col I fixed the issue by following the answer given by Andrew Cox

Answer (score 7):

This has been fixed in groovy.

Download xfwm4_4.14.5-1_amd64.deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/amd64/xfwm4/4.14.5-1

```
sudo dpkg -i xfwm4_4.14.5-1_amd64.deb
```

reboot

Comment: This bug has given me a headache. Thank you Andrew!

Comment: Oh, such a great hint. Brief and to the point!

Comment: A more generic sudo apt-get install xfwm4 worked for me.